# phpseclib zf2 Fatal Error calling class

Tags: zend-framework2, phpseclib

I am trying to configure phpseclib with zf2.

I am referring to https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib and I installed composer.
I saved the package inside vendor/phpseclib.

inside vendor/composer =>

```
<?php

// autoload_namespaces.php generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(__DIR__);
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
  'Zend\\' => $vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendframework/library/',
  'ZendTest\\' => $vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendframework/tests/',
  'phpseclib\\' => $vendorDir .  '/phpseclib/',
);
```

then as they suggest I create a php file with the following code:

```
<?php
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
$ssh = new \phpseclib\Net\SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
exit('Login Failed');
}
echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

I also add 
use phpseclib\Net;
use phpseclib\Net\SSH2;

to be sure

But I get this error:

Fatal error: Class 'phpseclib\Net\SSH2' not found in...

I am using Win8, Xampp and PHP5.5

My composer.json is:

```
{
"name": "phpseclib/phpseclib",
"type": "library",
"description": "PHP Secure Communications Library - Pure-PHP implementations of RSA, AES, SSH2, SFTP, X.509 etc.",
"keywords": [
    "security",
    "crypto",
    "cryptography",
    "encryption",
    "signature",
    "signing",
    "rsa",
    "aes",
    "blowfish",
    "twofish",
    "ssh",
    "sftp",
    "x509",
    "x.509",
    "asn1",
    "asn.1",
    "BigInteger"
    ],
"homepage": "http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net",
"license": "MIT",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "Jim Wigginton",
        "email": "terrafrost@php.net",
        "role": "Lead Developer"
    },
    {
        "name": "Patrick Monnerat",
        "email": "pm@datasphere.ch",
        "role": "Developer"
    },
    {
        "name": "Andreas Fischer",
        "email": "bantu@phpbb.com",
        "role": "Developer"
    },
    {
        "name": "Hans-Jürgen Petrich",
        "email": "petrich@tronic-media.com",
        "role": "Developer"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.0.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phing/phing": "~2.7",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "sami/sami": "~2.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~1.5"
},
"suggest": {
    "ext-mcrypt": "Install the Mcrypt extension in order to speed up a wide variety of cryptographic operations.",
    "ext-gmp": "Install the GMP (GNU Multiple Precision) extension in order to speed up arbitrary precision integer arithmetic operations.",
    "pear-pear/PHP_Compat": "Install PHP_Compat to get phpseclib working on PHP < 4.3.3."
},
"include-path": ["phpseclib/"],
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Crypt": "phpseclib/",
        "File": "phpseclib/",
        "Math": "phpseclib/",
        "Net": "phpseclib/",
        "System": "phpseclib/"
    },
    "files": [
        "phpseclib/Crypt/Random.php"
    ]
},
"extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "0.3-dev"
    }
}
}
```

My composer.json is

```
{
"name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
"description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "zf2"
],
"homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*",
    "doctrine/common" : ">=2.1",
    "phpseclib/phpseclib": "0.3.10"
},
```

}

Comment: Can you post your composer.json file? Unless you're using the 2.0 branch then you're probably using a version of phpseclib that is not namespace'd.

Comment: I edited my question and added the composer.json file thanks for checking

Comment: I was more interested in your composer.json - not in phpseclib's composer.json. Or does your project not have it's own composer.json? If so then how did you download phpseclib? The version that phpseclib.sourceforge.net mentions is 0.3.10, which is not namespaced. The namespace'd version exists at https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/tree/2.0

Comment: Yes in fact at the end i downloaded this. I have updated my question with the composer.json file of my project

Comment: It seems to work now. Please eventually tell me what i did wrong and what i should not do.

Comment: Thanks neubert. With the new package it works now!

Answer (score 1):

At the end with the suggestion of neubert I solved it.

I just needed to download the right package at https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/tree/2.0

and the execute php composer.phar install --dev and if not working I just changed my autoload_namespaces.php in the folder vendor/composer:

```
// autoload_namespaces.php generated by Composer
$vendorDir = dirname(__DIR__);
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Zend\\' => $vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendframework/library/',
    'ZendTest\\' => $vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendframework/tests/',
    'phpseclib\\' => $vendorDir .  '/phpseclib/',
);
```

The line 'phpseclib\' => $vendorDir .  '/phpseclib/', was the key for the solution